# Automatically show a tooltip in Twitter Bootstrap without putting the cursor

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

```
<a href="#" title="Twitter bootstrap" data-toggle="tooltip">bootstrap</a>
```

i want to show a tooltip without put the cursor.
is there any special attributes to do this?

Comment: This is definition of tooltip: "a message which appears when a cursor is positioned over an icon, image, hyperlink, or other element in a graphical user interface", and... you don't want that to happen.

Comment: Let me know what exactly do you want, as in, when the message should be displayed? When the page loads?

Comment: When the page load, a tooltip show 5 seconds and then tooltip hidden. any idea?

Comment: An old one, but be sure to select an answer if this helped you @LatiefAnwar :)

Answer (score 0):

In general you can show the tooltip from javascript code using       `$('#my-tooltip').tooltip('show')`. 
Your anchor tag would have to match the selector and you need to add `data-trigger="manual"` attribute

```
<a id="my-tooltip" href="#" title="Twitter bootstrap" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="manual">bootstrap</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [the Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips), you can manually show and hide tooltips with the corresponding methods. Not sure what your js looks like, but something like this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#tt-element').tooltip('show')
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('#tt-element').tooltip('hide')
  }, 5000)
}
```

Of course, you need to change your html to include `id="tt-element"`